# C++ / MPI: Properly define matrix size

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, gaussian

I'm trying to run a code of Serial and Parallel Gaussian Elimination using MPI. Here's a code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

using namespace std;

void serial_gaussian(double* A, double* b, double* y, int n)
{
    int i, j, k;

    cout << "In serial algorithm " << endl; 

    for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        for (j = k + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (A[k * n + k] != 0)
                A[k * n + j] = A[k * n + j] / A[k * n + k];
            else
                A[k * n + j] = 0;
        }

        if (A[k * n + k] != 0)
            y[k] = b[k] / A[k * n + k];
        else
            y[k] = 0.0; 

        A[k * n + k] = 1.0;

        for (i = k + 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (j = k + 1; j < n; j++)
                A[i * n + j] -= A[i * n + k] * A[k * n + j];

            b[i] -= A[i * n + k] * y[k];
            A[i * n + k] = 0.0;
        }
    }
}

void distribute_matrix(double* M, double* LM, int x, int y, int size, int rank)
{
    MPI_Status status; 
    int i, j, p;
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        for (p = size - 1; p >= 0; p--)
        {
            for (i = p; i < y; i += size)
                for (j = 0; j < x; j++)
                {
                    LM[(i / size) * x + j] = M[i * x + j];
                }
            if (p != 0)
                MPI_Send(LM, (y / size) * x, MPI_DOUBLE, p, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
    else
        MPI_Recv(LM, (y / size) * x, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}

void gather_matrix(double* M, double* LM, int x, int y, int size, int rank)
{
    MPI_Status status; 
    int i, j, p;

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        for (p = 0; p < size; p++)
        {
            if (p != 0)
                MPI_Recv(LM, (y / size) * x, MPI_DOUBLE, p, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            for (i = p; i < y; i += size)
                for (j = 0; j < x; j++)
                    M[i * x + j] = LM[(i / size) * x + j];
        }
    }
    else
        MPI_Send(LM, (y / size) * x, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

void print_matrix(double* M, int x, int y)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < x; j++)
            cout << M[i * x + j] << "   ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void parallel_gaussian(double* A, double* b, double* y, int n, int size, int rank)
{
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Request request;
    MPI_Comm com = MPI_COMM_WORLD;

    double* LA = new double[n * n / size];
    double* Lb = new double[n / size];
    double* Ly = new double[n / size];
    double* cur_row = new double[n + 1];
    double stime, ftime, tottime = 0;
    int i, j, k, np = (int)n / size;
    int pred, succ, start, flag = 1;
    int ksn, in, ink;

    pred = (size + (rank - 1)) % size;
    succ = (rank + 1) % size;

    distribute_matrix(A, LA, n, n, size, rank);
    distribute_matrix(b, Lb, 1, n, size, rank);

    for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        if ((k % size) == rank)
        {
            ksn = (k / size) * n;
            for (j = k + 1; j < n; j++)
                LA[ksn + j] = LA[ksn + j] / LA[ksn + k];
            Ly[k / size] = Lb[k / size] / LA[ksn + k];
            LA[ksn + k] = 1.0;

            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                cur_row[j] = LA[(k / size) * n + j];
            cur_row[n] = Ly[k / size];

            MPI_Send(cur_row, n + 1, MPI_DOUBLE, succ, 20, com);
        }
        else
        {
            MPI_Recv(cur_row, n + 1, MPI_DOUBLE, pred, 20, com, &status);
            if (succ != k % size)
            {
                MPI_Send(cur_row, n + 1, MPI_DOUBLE, succ, 20, com);
            }
        }

        start = (rank <= k % size) ? (int)k / size + 1 : (int)k / size;

        for (i = start; i < np; i++)
        {
            in = i * n;
            ink = in + k;

            for (j = k + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                LA[in + j] -= LA[ink] * cur_row[j];
            }
            Lb[i] -= LA[ink] * cur_row[n];
            LA[ink] = 0.0;
        }
    }
    gather_matrix(A, LA, n, n, size, rank);
    gather_matrix(y, Ly, 1, n, size, rank);
}

void print_equations(double* A, double* y, int n)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (A[i * n + j] != 0)
            {
                cout << A[i * n + j] << "x" << j;
                if (j < n - 1)
                    cout << " + ";
            }
            else
                cout << "    "; 
        }
        cout << " = " << y[i] << endl;
    }
}

void print_solution(double* A, double* y, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    double* x = new double[n];

    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        x[i] = y[i];
        for (j = n - 1; j > i; j--)
            x[i] -= x[j] * A[i * n + j];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i += 4)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < i + 4 && j < n; j++)
            cout << "x[" << j << "]=" << x[j] << " ";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double* A, * b, * y;
    double stime, ftime;
    int size, rank;

    int i, j, n, r;

    if (argc << 2) {
        cout << "Usage \n"; 
        cout << "   Arg1 = number of equations / unknows \n";
        return -1;
    }

    n = atoi(argv[1]);

    A = new double[n * n];
    b = new double[n];
    y = new double[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        b[i] = 0.0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            r = rand();
            A[i * n + j] = r;
            b[i] += j * r;
        }
    }

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm com = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
    
    MPI_Comm_size(com, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(com, &rank);

    stime = MPI_Wtime();

    if (size == 1)
    {
        serial_gaussian(A, b, y, n);
        ftime = MPI_Wtime();
        printf("Total time is %f \n", ftime - stime);
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Finalize();
    }

    else
    {
        if ((n % size) != 0)
        {
            cout << "Unknowns must be multiple of processors." << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            parallel_gaussian(A, b, y, n, size, rank);
            if (rank == 0)
            {
                ftime = MPI_Wtime();
                printf("Total time is %f \n", ftime - stime);
            }
            MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Finalize();
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

While running this code in command line using:

```
mpiexec -np 2 Gauss
```

I only get the next text:

> Usage    Arg1 = Arg1 = number of equations / unknows Usage    Arg1 =
> Arg1 = number of equations / unknows

How properly define matrix size here, please help modify this code? Thanks!

Comment: Did you write this code yourself? Your main program expects commandline argument but you're not supplying any.

Comment: No, it's educational code. Need to understand, how does it work, can be corrected if there are mistakes

Comment: Also I run mpiexec -np 2 Gauss 10 in hope that it will work with 10x10 matrix, but still got the same result

Comment: 1. I suspect `argc << 2` is a typo. Change to `argc<2`. 2. You can not always assume that each process get the commandline arguments. I would read them on process zero and broadcast to the others.